# Custom Post Type Slug URL generating issue

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, custom-post-type, permalinks, slug

I have created a custom post type and added the slug rewrite as

'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'media/tvshows',
                            'with_front'=> true)

When I creating a new post for this Custom Post Type, in the Permalink URL slug value is not added. I can see http://www.mytestsite.org/postname/ and not as http://www.mytestsite.org/media/tvshows/postname/

But when in Admin Setting -> Permalink page, I can see Permalink structure for my Created Custom Post Type as http://www.mytestsite.org/media/tvshows/%postname%/ and has_archive: false / with_front: true

Comment: Try re-saving your permalink settings in the admin panel.

Comment: I have done, but not updating